# Python TTY Control

Tags: python, linux, unix, tty, termios

I guess I'm not clear on what what the function of the getty/agetty/mgetty programs are on a linux/unix machine.  I can start a shell on a tty with something like this:

```
TTY = '/dev/tty3'

cpid = os.fork()
if cpid == 0:
    os.closerange(0, 4)
    sys.stdin = open(TTY, 'r')
    sys.stdout = open(TTY, 'w')
    sys.stderr = open(TTY, 'w')
    os.execv(('/bin/bash',), ('bash',))
```

..and if i switch over to tty3, there is a shell running- but some keystrokes are ignored / are never being sent to the shell. the shell knows the TTY settings are not correct because bash will say something like 'unable to open tty, job control disabled'

I know the 'termios' module has functions to change the settings on the TTY, which is what the 'tty' module uses, but i am unable to find an example of python setting the TTY correctly and starting a shell.  I feel like it should be something simple, but i don't know where to look.

looking at the source for the *etty programs didn't help me- C looks like greek to me :-/

Maybe im just not looking for the right terms?  Anyone replaced the *etty programs with Python in the past and have an explanation they would care to share?

Thanks for entertaining my basic question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see at least two things you're missing - there may be more:

Firstly, you need to call `setsid()` in the child process after closing the old standard input/standard output, and before opening the new TTY.  This does two important things - it makes your new process the leader of a new session, and it disassociates it from its previous controlling terminal (merely closing that terminal is *not* sufficient).  This will mean that when you open the new tty, it will become the controlling terminal, which is what you want.

Secondly, you need to set the `TERM` environment variable to match the new tty.

Comment: os.setsid() is all it took! I knew it had to be easy. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the source of the *tty* programs, to see what they do.

My guess is that they mostly issue a bunch of ioctl commands to initialise the terminal into the mode that programs normally expect (e.g. for login etc). However some of them may also prompt for a username (not password; login does that).